# Can't delete php sessions

Tags: command-line, server

I have read dozens of posts on his subject, yet cannot find a solution that works for me.

I have a user account. PHP sessions for that account are stored in

`/home/user/tmp`

Apache start tossing errors that i can't open sessions because the device is full.

df and df -i both show me that the device has plenty of space.

So I look to he /home/user/tmp directory. It shows the size of the directory is 901MB.

I wan to delete the session files from the directory.

I have tried

`rm -rf /home/user/tmp/sess_*`

I let his run for over an hour then used `cntr+C` to kill the command. The directory still says 901 MB.

I have rebooted the system, the directory still shows at 901MB.

I have tried

`find /home/*/tmp -type f -name 'sess_*' -ctime +5 -delete`

Just like with `rm -rf` I let the command run for over an hour and killed it.

The directory still shows 901MB.

I am issuing these commands as root user. I am using ubuntu 16.04. This is a server so only command line options will work.

What can I do to remove these session files?

Answer (score 3):

Often you can't delete session files even with command like `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*` because a path name expansion occurs BEFORE the sudo (https://serverfault.com/a/851261/591003).

You can try another command like `sudo sh -c "rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*"` but if you have tons of files you'll get an answer that `rm: Argument list too long` because the list of session files is usually very huge (up to millions of files).

I propose a really simple way:

1. Create a new folder *sessions_new*: `mkdir /var/lib/php/sessions_new`
2. Set the same permissions as for old *sessions* directory: `sudo chmod --reference=sessions sessions_new`
3. Do the same with ownership: `sudo chown --reference=sessions sessions_new`
4. Kill it! `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions`
5. You don't need to wait a result for a long time. You can check it immediately in a new terminal window by `sudo find /var/lib/php/sessions/. -type f|wc -l`. This command counts the number of files inside your *sessions* folder. Run it two times. If the second time you run the command, you get a lower number than the first time, then the process is going in the right direction.
6. Wait for a long time :P
7. When process has finished just rename the *session_new* directory: `mv /var/lib/php/sessions_new /var/lib/php/sessions`

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you. But there is an issue with my sessions files, it is not automatically removing, i've to repeat this process every week to remove session files. I'm using `LEMP Stack` on Ubuntu. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a lot of small files, deleting can take some significant time. Let it run until it finishes. It should eventually finish.

I did a quick test on my system, and deleting 100k empty files on a SSD disk with ext4 took 1.14 seconds. If you have tens of millions of files, it may take a good while.

Comment: I would suspect you are correct, but after an hour of running, the directory size should have decreased to some extent.

Comment: Let it run overnight.

Answer (score 0):

I think *Dzmitry Kulahin's* [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300583/1040551) works, but in my case I ran out of space so I couldn't create the new "sessions_new" directory. I solved using command line php in interactive mode:

```
sudo php -a
```

**please note** that you must use `sudo`, otherwise subsequent commands have no privileges to operate.

Write this sequence on a single line, it is necessary to write it on a single line because in interactive mode, each press of the enter key immediately executes the command:

```
$listfile = scandir("/var/lib/php/sessions/");
foreach ($listfile as $file) {
    if (!is_dir("/var/lib/php/sessions/".$file)) {
        unlink("/var/lib/php/sessions/".$file);
    }
}
```

Press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key and the files start deleting.

You can monitor the cancellation by opening another terminal and typing:

```
sudo find /var/lib/php/sessions/. -type f|wc -l
```

It will show you the number of files in the directory, repeating this the command several times you will see the number go down as the files are deleted.